# Safari in macOS 10.12.2 is blinking

Tags: safari, reading-list

Not sure why some sites in my reading list is blinking/flickering.
Notice those site that blinks has a blank icon.
Anyone having this problem too?
Happening in private mode too.

Safari  10.0.2 (12602.3.12.0.1)

Comment: I get very hight cpu usage when the side bar is open as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Fixed it by clearing caches from the `Develop` menu and restarting Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this -- same MacOS and Safari versions as original question. I exited Safari and restarted it, and the problem stopped.

Comment: I've had this issue for a couple weeks, restarting Safari seems to be the only reliably way of getting it to stop.